# Table with text aligned at a specific point and setting specific row width

Tags: tables, tabbing

I am facing some issues with creating a table, where the content is aligned at a certain point (in this case '='). For this purpose I am using the 'tabbing' environment, which is not maybe the best solution.
The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|>{\Centering}m{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{0pt}|}
   \hline
    {\it Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\it Diameter $\left[ \mathrm{mm} \right]$} & \vspace{10pt} \vspace{10pt} \\ \hline \hline
   Type A & \vspace{-8pt} {\begin{tabbing} \hspace{0.7cm} \=$d_{a1}$ \ \=$= 1$ \\
                                                          \>$d_{a2}$   \>$= 2$ \\
                                                          \>$d_{a3}$   \>$= 3$ \\
                                                          \>$d_{a4}$   \>$= 4$
                           \end{tabbing}} &\\ \hline
   Type B &  {\begin{tabbing} \hspace{0.7cm} \=$d_{b1}$ \ \=$= 1$ \\
                                             \>$d_{b2}$   \>$= 2$ \\
                                             \>$d_{a3}$   \>$= 3$ \\
                                             \>$d_{a4}$   \>$= 4$
             \end{tabbing}} &\\ \hline
   Type C & {\begin{tabbing} \hspace{0.7cm} \=$d_{c1}$ \ \=$= 1$ \\
                                            \>$d_{c2}$   \>$= 2$ \\
                                            \>$d_{c3}$   \>$= 3$ \\
                                            \>$d_{c4}$   \>$= 4$
             \end{tabbing}} &\\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Firstly I am struggling to reduce the spaces created by using the 'tabbing' environment above and below the text in the cell. Secondly an auxiliary column is used to increase the width only of the first row and even after setting `m{0pt}` the column has a width, which is not desired.
So I would be grateful if someone could help with the given problems by sharing a solution/explanation or could propose a different approach to achieve the same result.

The output table with indications is:
[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Maybe it's just my system, but where you have specified `\it`, the text is upright.  But you shouldn't be using `\it` anyhow -- `\textit{...}` or `\itshape` is the proper LaTeX method.  Also, the type in the table is sans serif, and I don't see any request for that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton When I was adding the annotations in PDF, the text has been converted automatically to 'sans serif', so it is not an issue. I am pretty new to LaTeX, so thank you for pointing out the proper method for using `\it`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  (My system has been misbehaving lately, so I'm actually glad that's not the cause.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am going to upload a different image to avoid similar misunderstandings in future

Comment: Much nicer.  Here are some suggestions; I'll try later to test, but this is what I'd start with.  Use only two columns, set to the width you want, and set both centered.  To get the height, somewhere (doesn't matter where) in one column, set a zero-width rule: `\vrule height15pt depth 5pt width0pt`.

Comment: For the second column, use the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` (wrap it in `$` so it's recognized as math), and each line looks like `d_{a1} &= 1 \\` (omit the double backslash from the last line of a group).  The `&` will be the alignment point, and the fact that it's buried between `$...$` will apply the appropriate spacing.  I'll try to test this a bit later; I don't like posting answers that aren't tested and have a recognizable output image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be close to what you're looking for.

The `aligned` subsidiary environment from `amsmath` works in horizontal mode.  It requires a vertical positioning option to keep it in proper alignment with the text in the first column.  This avoids the extra vertical space above and below the `tabbing` environment, as well as making the code much simpler because everything is automatically in math mode.  I kept the positioning instructions from `ragged2e`, but there are suitable ones that don't require a separate package; other questions in this forum use them and should not be too hard to find.

Adding extra vertical space to the first row just required addition of a zero-width vertical rule to the columns that were occupied; it proved to be necessary to add it to both columns, and the values for height and depth had to be experimented on to get the proper balance,  The code `\vrule` is plain TeX; there's a LaTeX equivalent, but I'd have to look it up.  (I learned plain TeX before LaTeX existed, and some things work the same way in either; but don't assume that, as I noted in a comment about `\it`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{|>{\Centering}m{3cm}|>{\Centering}m{3cm}|}
   \hline
    \vrule height13pt depth7pt width0pt
    \textit{Type} &
    \vrule height13pt depth7pt width0pt
    \textit{Diameter} [mm] \\ \hline \hline
   Type A & $\begin{aligned}[b]                                                 
                             d_{a1} &= 1 \\                                     
                             d_{a2} &= 2 \\                                     
                             d_{a3} &= 3 \\                                     
                             d_{a4} &= 4                                        
              \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline
   Type B & $\begin{aligned}[b]
                             d_{b1} &= 1 \\
                             d_{b2} &= 2 \\
                             d_{b3} &= 3 \\
                             d_{b4} &= 4
              \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline                                          
   Type C & $\begin{aligned}[b]
                             d_{c1} &= 1 \\
                             d_{c2} &= 2 \\
                             d_{c3} &= 3 \\
                             d_{c4} &= 4
              \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your help and further explanation of the proposed solution. I was not aware of the `\vrule` command. Il will implement it in future tables when necessary. Thank you.